# How to link sent and received messages in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a dating site where people can send and receive messages from and to each other.
I have a table "users" which contains a user-ID and information like age, name, etc...
There is also a table "messages" which contains a message-ID, from, to, datetime and the message itself.
I can store the messages and in my table it shows like: user 23 send message x to user 54.

But now user 54 needs to reply to user 23 and I have no idea how to link a next message to this original message.

The idea is that in the end there is some sort of mail conversation visible between the 2 users.

I don't want to use some sort of message board or chat solution.

Does anyone has an idea how to handle this or how I can link send and received messages to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to have a Conversations table, and each message would contain a Conversation-ID. When sending an initial message, you create a new conversation, while replies copy the conversation ID from the previous message.

Another way would be for each message to contain an In-Reply-To field, which would contain the message ID of the previous message. Then you can recreate the whole flow of the conversation.

You could also do both, since the conversation ID would make it easy to find all the messages in the conversation with a simple join, and then you could show the thread using In-Reply-To.

Comment: I will try to use the solution with the in-reply-to field you provided. I think I see how I can do it that way. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this, e.g.:

- add another field "reference": The row for an answer would store the message ID of the original message there
- if necessary add another field "referencetype" `ENUM('RE','FWD', ...)` if there are different possible ways of referencing a message

Answer (score 0):

Misread the request.

You're going to need a new column in the messages table and you could keep the root messageID in that column so you could see "up the chain" whenever some one loads a conversation they get everything with that root messageID in order of date you just need to store that messageID somewhere to be referenced when you place new messages back into your table.

Comment: It seems like you misunderstood the questin.